# Downloaded File Size 0

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, servlets, alfresco

I'm trying here to add a specific dialog bean for action on Alfresco Explorer that supposed to download a specific docx file. The code is working fine when I hit the download action, it downloads the file but as mentioned in my question title, the file size is 0 bytes.

I'm using this to do that:

```
public class NewFormDialog extends BaseDialogBean {

protected String aspect;

protected String finishImpl(FacesContext context, String outcome)
        throws Exception {

    download(aspect);

    // // get the space the action will apply to
    // NodeRef nodeRef = this.browseBean.getActionSpace().getNodeRef();
    //
    // // resolve the fully qualified aspect name
    // QName aspectToAdd = Repository.resolveToQName(this.aspect);
    //
    // // add the aspect to the space
    // getNodeService().addAspect(nodeRef, aspectToAdd, null);
    //
    // // return the default outcome
    return outcome;
}

public boolean getFinishButtonDisabled() {
    return false;
}

public String getFinishButtonLabel() {
    return "Download";
}

public void download(String pAspect) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String filename = pAspect;
    String filepath = "\\";
    BufferedInputStream buf = null;
    ServletOutputStream myOut = null;

    try {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc
                .getExternalContext().getResponse();

        myOut = response.getOutputStream();
        File myfile = new File(filepath + filename);

        // set response headers
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="
                + filename);

        response.setContentLength((int) myfile.length());

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(myfile);
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(input);
        int readBytes = 0;

        // read from the file; write to the ServletOutputStream
        while ((readBytes = buf.read()) != -1)
            myOut.write(readBytes);
        myOut.flush();
        response.flushBuffer();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new ServletException(ioe.getMessage());

    } finally {
        // close the input/output streams
        if (myOut != null)
            myOut.close();
        if (buf != null)
            buf.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    }
}

public String getAspect() {
    return aspect;
}

public void setAspect(String aspect) {
    this.aspect = aspect;
}
}
```

I tried every solution that I found by none works.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `File.length()` method returns `0` if the file does not exist.  Check to make sure that the file exists.

**Tip:** The [Apache Commons IO library](http://commons.apache.org/io/) simplifies many I/O related tasks.  For example, the following code snippet streams the contents of a file to the servlet response:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ...
File myfile = ...
InputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
  in = new FileInputStream(myfile);
  out = response.getOutputStream();
  IOUtils.copy(in, out);
} finally {
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(in); //checks for null
  IOUtils.closeQuietly(out); //checks for null
}
```

Comment: Actually I think I'm mistaking the path here.

I use something like this for filepath "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/d/a/workspace/SpacesStore/space1/" but I'm restarting the server to try with this:

"localhost:8080\\alfresco\\d\\a\\workspace\\SpacesStore\\space1\\"

I just checked Tomcat's log file and I found this

`Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: File Not Found
 at
 ... 54 more`

Thank you for the Tip by the way.

Comment: Problem Solved. It was a path problem, I had to do something like "C:\\Alfresco\\". Now Its working perfectly.

Thank you once again for your Tip @Michael .

Comment: Sorry I just saw your message now. Done!

Comment: @Emowpy Oh ok, it's not a prob. :)